# How to underline columns with gaps in the line?

Tags: latex

I am looking for a way to put this into a table with the underlining going correctly. What I want is the following: both columns are underlined, but it is not one connected line. I would like to have a small gap in between the two. How can I obtain this?

I know I can underline columns with `\cline{1}` and `\cline{2}` but this makes them connected, which is what I do not want.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    3 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an empty column and `hhline` (or `cline`)

```
%...
\usepackage{hhline}
%...
\begin{tabular}{c@{\ }c@{\ }c}
  3 & & 3 \\
  \hhline{-~-}
\end{tabular}
```